# How to incorporate an environment variable into a systemd option assignment statement

Tags: services, systemd

Consider this [Service] option setting in a systemd ".service" unit file:

WorkingDirectory=/var/www/my-working-dir

Is there syntax for assigning an environment var to WorkingDirectory, something like:

WorkingDirectory=$(MY_WORKING_DIR)

Answer (score 0):

No. `man systemd.exec` documents `WorkingDirectory=` and no mention of substitution is mentioned there.

(By contrast, `man systemd.service` explicitly documents some substitions for `ExecStart=`).

As an alternative, perhaps one of the [Specifiers documented in `man systemd.unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Specifiers) will work for your case.